# Python: Two lists to be compared for format match and made into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm using python 3: I have two lists and I want to have them combined in a dictionary using similar information:

```py
first_list = [('1234', 'abcd', 'John Doe', 'good_status'), 
              ('1234', 'efgh', 'John Doe', 'good_status'), 
              ('1234', 'hijk', 'John Doe', 'bad_status'), 
              ('5566', 'abjk', 'George Washington', 'good_status'), 
              ('7889', 'zyxw', 'Jane Austin', bad_status')]
```

The second list might be:

```py
second_list = [('1234', 'John Doe', 'abcd efgh hijk'), 
               ('5566', 'George Washington', 'abjk'), 
               ('7889', 'Jane Austin', 'zyxw')]
```

Desired Dictionary output:

```py
dictionary = {'1234' : ('John Doe', 'abcd_good efgh_good hijk_baad')
              '5566': ('George Washington', 'abjk_good')
              '7889': ('Jane Austin', 'zyxw_bad')
              }
```

In `first_list` that entry `[0]` and `[2]` match the entry `[0]` and entry `[1]` of `second_list`.

`first_list` has entry `[1]` and `[3]` which should come together and match with `second_list[2]`

Oh... and the two lists are not really lined up like, index `0` of might not be the same name as index `0` of `second_list`.

I'm new and kinda in over my head, could use any advice.

Comment: one thing to keep in mind when trying to line up the elements from the two lists is the 'key'.  What is the unique identifier? In this case I'm assuming it's the 4 digit numbers.  This means you'll end up looping through both lists.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is only to use `first_list` without the reference of `second_list`.

The following code can be runnable under the environment of `>=python 3.6`, since I used `f-string`.

The full code listed below:

```py
first_list = [
    ('1234', 'abcd', 'John Doe', 'good_status'), 
    ('1234', 'efgh', 'John Doe', 'good_status'), 
    ('1234', 'hijk', 'John Doe', 'bad_status'), 
    ('5566', 'abjk', 'George Washington', 'good_status'), 
    ('7889', 'zyxw', 'Jane Austin', 'bad_status')]


dictionary = dict()

# Loop over the given list
for i in first_list:

    # Extract the index
    new_key = i[0]

    # If the new key is not existed, 
    # make a new item and initialize it with empty string
    # The reason for using `list` instead of `tuple` 
    # is that `list` object is mutable
    if new_key not in dictionary.keys():
        new_name = i[2]
        dictionary.update({new_key: [new_name,""]})

    # Parse the new status string 
    # and append it into the existing string
    # If you are using python version under 3.6, 
    # try to use `format()` function
    new_str = f"{i[1]}_{i[3].split('_')[0]}"
    dictionary[new_key][1] += f" {new_str}"

# Transfer the lists to tuples using "dict comprehension"
dictionary = {k:tuple(v) for (k, v) in dictionary.items()}

print(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a solution with two functions, `make_dict_from_list` and `match_two_dicts`.  There are ways to make these more succinct with list comprehensions, but I wrote them the long way so it's more clear what they're doing.

```py
def make_dict_from_list(list):
    temp_dict={}
    for record in list:
        for word in record:
            if word == record[0]:
                temp_dict[record[0]] = []
            else:
                temp_dict[record[0]].append(word)
    return temp_dict
```

This method makes a temporary dictionary, and iterates through the list, record by record.  It makes the word at the first position (`if word = record[0]`) the key of the dictionary, and sets an empty array as the value of that key.  If it's not the first word (i.e. `else`), it `append`s any other words in the line to that array.  Next you can call these methods to make your dictionaries.  Expected result:

```py
>>>>make_dict_from_list(first_list)
{'1234': ['hijk', 'John Doe', 'bad_status'], '5566': ['abjk', 'George Washington', 'good_status'], '7889': ['zyxw', 'Jane Austin', 'bad_status']}

>>>>make_dict_from_list(second_list)
{'1234': ['John Doe', 'abcd efgh hijk'], '5566': ['George Washington', 'abjk'], '7889': ['Jane Austin', 'zyxw']}
```

Now we can make our second method:

```py
def match_two_dicts(dict1, dict2):
    for index1, key1 in enumerate(dict1):
        for index2, key2 in enumerate(dict2):
            if key1 == key2:
                print(f"ID {key1}: match at dict1[{index1}], dict2[{index2}]")
```

This splits the entries in `dict1` & `dict2` into a list of key-value pairs.  We use `enumerate` so we have an index of our position in each dictionary.  Then, if the IDs (i.e., the keys of each record) match, we can print out the positions of the match.

Expected result:

```py
>>> match_two_dicts(dict1, dict2)
ID 1234: match at dict1[0], dict2[0]
ID 5566: match at dict1[1], dict2[1]
ID 7889: match at dict1[2], dict2[2]
```

edit: I just noticed that you have duplicate IDs in your first list, which my solution does not account for.  If this is necessary for your application, you will need to modify the code to use a list of dicts with one key, instead of a single dict with multiple keys.  If this is a problem for you let me know.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up griding it out on my own, but your comment would have helppppped so much. Thanks!  But yeah the duplicate keys was important... although the 4 digit number was what I wanted to be the keys of the dictionary, I needed the dictionary entry for a key to be expanded with aditional information when a list tuple had the same key as was already present in the dictionary.  Took a while to work it out, but I used a similar approach as you with if statements for if 4 digit pin is already in dict.keys ()

Answer (score 0):

You need a double for loop to check for the status of each item and combine them into a dictionary based on the matches.

```py
first_list = [
    ('1234', 'abcd', 'John Doe', 'good_status'),
    ('1234', 'efgh', 'John Doe', 'good_status'),
    ('1234', 'hijk', 'John Doe', 'bad_status'),
    ('5566', 'abjk', 'George Washington', 'good_status'),
    ('7889', 'zyxw', 'Jane Austin', 'bad_status')
]

second_list = [
    ('1234', 'John Doe', 'abcd efgh hijk'),
    ('5566', 'George Washington', 'abjk'),
    ('7889', 'Jane Austin', 'zyxw')
    ]




def CreateDict(list1, list2):

    #Dictionary to be created.
    dictionary = {}

    #Go through each given data.
    for search_key in list2:
        dict_data  = [search_key[1]]
        status     = ""

        #Go through the data we must check for the status.
        for element in list1:

            #If the number and the names match.
            if search_key[0] == element[0] and search_key[1] == element[2]:

                #Check the status of each data.
                data = search_key[2].split(" ")
                for d in data:
                    if d in element:

                        #         Data| status without the _status  |      add a space at the end.
                        status += d+"_"+element[3].replace("_status", "") +" "


        #Remove the last space added on the status string.
        status = status[:len(status)-1]

        #Append the status data on the list.
        dict_data.append(status)

        #Append the dict_data using the number as a key.
        dictionary[str(search_key[0])] = dict_data

    #Return the dictionary.
    return dictionary


print(CreateDict(first_list, second_list))
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! I ended up sticking to it and getting an OK enough result on my own. However, you all gave me some really great ideas for version 2 and I learned a lot by doing it then reading your ideas later. Thank you all so very much for your time!